# Slider to icons over image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image with icons on it as shown in below image.

[image]

The icons on the image are clickable and whenever i click on any of the icon it should be moved to center. How can i do this???

**index.php**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 service_img">
        <img src="images/Services.jpg">
        <ul>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">   
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/services_icons/Emerging market penetration.png"></a></li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/services_icons/Emerging market penetration.png"></a></li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/services_icons/Emerging market penetration.png"></a></li>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/services_icons/Emerging market penetration.png"></a></li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/services_icons/Emerging market penetration.png"></a></li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/services_icons/Emerging market penetration.png"></a></li>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><br><br>
```

**text.css**

```
   .bg-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}
.bg-img:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #002f4b, #dc4225);*/
  opacity: .6;
}
```

**The icon i clicked should be moved to center**. Please, help me out with solution get solution.

Thank you in Advance!!!

Comment: I'm assuming that you need slider on click of img icon which u have given on <li>,right?

Comment: @KishorVelayutham Yeah that is what i require.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on the image carousel,which helps you to achieve what you are expecting.

Try your image for `carousel indicator`. I have given default one of carousel.

Change the `css` and `div` position based on your requirement.

Let me know it is what you are looking for.

Check out the working edited fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KishorVelayutham/yhevvxz4/26/

Hope this helps..!

Comment: Thanks for help. But i need slider for icons on the image.

Comment: you wanted to add icons for that dot img ,right ??@suvasishsahoo

Comment: Check out the edited code. added the fiddle. Let me know it works as u expect.@suvasishsahoo

Comment: The background image is static and icons should be sliding.I want slider for the icons on the image.

Comment: Share your code @suvasishsahoo.It will easy for me to understand. I'm not getting why you wanted to slide the icon on the image.

Answer (score 0):

[Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html) is the best option for your problem.

```
<div style="background-image:url('images/Services.jpg');">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/services_icons/Emerging market penetration.png"></a></div>
            <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/services_icons/Emerging market penetration.png"></a></div>
            <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/services_icons/Emerging market penetration.png"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

you need to wrap the carousel in background image div, this plugin provides various option to customise your carousel even on mobile view as well.

Hope this may help you.